# What is the purpose of result variables in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran95

In Fortran, there are two standard ways to return a result from a function. The first one is by assigning the return value of the function to the function name.

```
function foo()
    integer :: foo

    foo = 10
end function foo
```

The second form, standardized in Fortran 90 is through a "result" variable.

```
function foo result(res)
    integer :: res

    res = 10
 end function foo
```

Calling either form of the function returns the value 10. My question is, what was the rationale of the Fortran 90 committee for introducing result variables? Were they standardizing a common practice? Or were they allowing programs to be more modular by not tying the function name to a function result. For example, in the second version of `foo()`, the name of the function `foo()` could be changed to `bar()` and the function would still work as expected when called.

However, I may be wrong. Does anyone know what the actual rationale was for introducing result variables?

Comment: Note that if you just want to change the name of the function, you don't need to change the body if you use result, so it is more convenient

Comment: @AnthonyScemama Yes, I believe I mentioned that in the question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Introduced at the same time as the `result` was *recursion*.  Before we get to how a recursive function comes about, some clarification on what a result variable is.

The function result is always returned through a result variable, whether `result` is used or not.<sup>1</sup> With `result` the result variable has the name specified, and without it the result variable has the same name as the function.  In this latter case use of the name is a reference to the result variable and not the function.

So, if the function `foo` has result variable `foo` then we can't do direct recursion:

```
recursive function foo(n)
  foo = foo(n-1) ! Oh dear
end function
```

`result` comes about so that we can have

```
recursive function foo(n) result(res)
  res = foo(n-1) ! Yay
end function
```

---

[1] Well, this is true up until Fortran 2008, when the definition of *variable* changed.  For modern Fortran use instead the term *function result*.

Comment: So is it mostly for recursive function?

Comment: It is required to allow recursive functions, but is also useful in providing a more manageable name inside a function's definition: `function long_and_descriptive_function_name () result(res)`.