# Fortran function for geometric series

Tags: function, fortran, fortran90

I am implementing this equation with a Fortran function. 
[image: geometric series equation]

Write call in function (g) consistently returns 6, but when I call function in program (z) output depends, e.g., 
-2123950080
-529463296
929961984.

Why g and z are not the same? What should I change in function to accomplish geometric series calculation?

```
function  geomSeries(n)
implicit none
integer :: i, n, g = 0, x = 1, geomSeries

g = 1 + x
do i = 2, n
    g = g + x**i
end do
write (*,*) g
return
end function geomSeries

program geomFunc
implicit none
integer :: n = 5, geomSeries, z

z =  geomSeries(n)
write (*,*) z
end program geomFunc
```

P.S. Ideally I would like it to be pure function, as I don't see how it produces side effects, but haven't managed to compile it that way (why?).

Comment: Writing is a side effect.

Comment: Your variables g and x are saved and are initialized *only once*. We have duplicates.

Comment: Rather more crucially, you don't assign to the function result `geomseries`.  `g` is not the same thing.

Comment: Ups, yes this is actually the immediate problem, the linked one will only appear after a second call.

Comment: Thanks, assigning geomSeries = g did the trick! I'm new to Fortran and I didn't know function returns only what's assigned to function name, because I'm used to passing different variables to return in Python or R.

Comment: @tRash a function statement could be `function geomSeries(n) result(g)`. More information at [wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fortran/Fortran_procedures_and_functions)

Comment: Or, indeed, in the link above https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31061507/what-is-the-purpose-of-result-variables-in-fortran